# Debug.WriteLine command does not appear any output

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget-package, visual-studio-2019

I have .Net project as nuget package. I am creating new project and adding this package to my new project. Nuget package project has `Debug.WriteLine` commands but I do not see any ouput in new project's console when project run on Debug mode.

is there any setting to enable that in Visual Studio 2019?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I guess, the methods from the class Debug works only if the build is 'Debug' build. If you build with 'Release' then these will be skipped. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: It's `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` then yes, the package has to be compiled in debug but you also need a configured **trace listener** (for example to write them to a log file). It's not meant to be used to output something to the console (even if a trace listener might do exactly that).

Answer (score 2):

The libraries (*.dll files) you got and are using from the nuget packages are most probably compiled in a Release configuration. So regardless of the package code having Debug.WriteLine methods these methods were omitted while compiling and are not present in the running code.

If you want to see the Debug.WriteLine outputs from the packages (actually rarely needed), than you have either to find a Debug build binary of the packages or to get the code and build it yourself in the Debug configuration, than use the resulting binaries.

Restoring nugets in a specific configuration, but not sure if it works: [nuget restore with configuration](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5895)

The following might also be related and help you: [debugging-nuget-package](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/01/29/debugging-nuget-package/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions